# jQuery Multiply Values based on Text input field

Tags: jquery

I am currently looking for a method to multiply 2 different value based upon the input of a numeric input type field

Here my code:

```
    <div class="variation-price">
        <span class="amount">114.00</span>
        <span class="unit">50</span>
        <span class="weight">g</span>
    </div>

    <input type="number" id="quantity" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="20" name="quantity" value="1" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

[image]

This one, currently shows 114.00 /50 g based upon my preselected value of 1 in the input field, however I would like this to automatically change and multiply based upon the number entered.

E.g. the output should update to 228.00 /100 g if I would enter the number 2, or 342.00 /150 g if I would enter 3 etc.

Is there a quick and easy way to have this achieved using jQuery? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? The only bits of this that seem jQuery related to me would be the event listener and the setting text. Have a look for jQuery's `.on()` and `.text()` methods and give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook to the `change` event of your input and execute the following function:

```
jQuery("#quantity").change(function(){
  var amount = parseFloat(jQuery(".amount").attr("data-init-amount"));
  var unit = parseFloat(jQuery(".unit").attr("data-init-unit"));
  var multiplier = parseInt(jQuery("#quantity").val());
  jQuery(".amount").html(amount * multiplier);
  jQuery(".unit").html(unit * multiplier);
});
```

Comment: It'll really help if you make a fiddle, I run that code in the console and there's no syntax error

Comment: Okay I managed to edit this and have it working now - thank you very much @Velimir Tchatchevsky for pointing the right way!

Comment: After testing this, I have noticed that this not works 100% correctly. Please have a look at the JSFiddle I've created : https://jsfiddle.net/hznyv9fd/ For instance when I'm on 3, the weight (currently 50 in default value) should update to 150 but it applies the same value as for the price - also I've noticed that when I'm going backwards it is still multiplying

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected, you need to keep the initial values too. I've updated the answer, here's the updated fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/wvxjzL23/

Comment: Absolutely amazing - you're a life saver. Thank you Mr. Velimir Tchatchevsky

Comment: Is there a possibility to have the decimals showing as well? currently facing that issue